GraphDB visual graph picks random rdfs:label as a node label
In my RDF data I am using several labels from SKOS. My concepts have exactly one skos:prefLabel, various skos:altLabels and some have skos:hiddenLabel. GraphDB allows me to visualise the graph, using one of the labels. But all of the SKOS labels are subclasses of rdfs:label, though GraphDB picks one of the labels randomly to use it as a label in visual graph.
Is there a way (without changing the data permanently) to pick one specific label (skos:prefLabel) to be visualized as a label in the visual graph?

You can create a custom visual graph config and use Edge basics -> RDFS or SKOS label and specify which label you want to be used.

